# Comparing two json files : shell scripting

Tags: json, shell, diff, jq

I would like to compare two json files which look like the following:

```
[
   {
      "type" : 1,
      "children" : {
         "nsubj" : {
            "role" : "topic",
            "POS" : [
               "noun"
            ]
         }
      },
      "role" : "vehicle",
      "POS" : [
         "noun"
      ]
   },
```

and the other is in the similar format, but there are some differences between the two because one json file is  made up of 3336 lines, while another is made up of 3724 lines. I would like to write a shell script which would compare the two line by line and whenever it finds a difference, output the line number where the difference occurred.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just use diff. Like in

```
diff --unified file1.json file2.json
```

Comment: Yes, I already tried this, but I am not too sure what the meaning of the headings are like @@ -1,2841 +1,2721 @@ for example

Comment: If you don't use 'unified' flag, then you'll see something like "9c9". It means line 9 changed.

Comment: could you explain the notation for the unified flag, basically is does it mean lines 1 to 2841 need to be changed? and similarly lines 1 to 2721 need to be changed in the second json file?

Answer (score 27):

To compare json files you should convert them so they have same order of keys. Very good tool for this job is *jq* (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) where you can do:

```
jq -S . fileA.json > fileA_fmt.json
jq -S . fileB.json > fileB_fmt.json
```

then, you can use your favourite tool for text file comparison. I like *kdiff3* for GUI or just plain *diff* when in pure command-line e.g.:

```
diff fileA_fmt.json fileB_fmt.json
```

Comment: Very good tool indeed. Just `brew install jq` to install it on MacOS

Comment: One thing to note is that you have to use a different file for the output. I attempted to write over the same file and it ends up leaving you with an empty file.

Answer (score 7):

Just to update on the answer from bartolomeon_n, you can actually do this all on one line.

```
diff <(jq -S . fileA.json) <(jq -S . fileB.json)
# or, with nice columns and colours:
diff -y --left-column --color <(jq -S . fileA.json) <(jq -S . fileB.json)
```

Comment: Great! Also removes the need to create (and clean up) of temporary files.