# Compare two json files with same name but different values in two files

Tags: python, json, shell, jq

I have two json files with content like following :

File1 :

```
    {
      "name": "SES_ENABLED",
      "value": "true"
    },
    {  
        "name":"SES_ADDRESS",
        "value":"email-xxxxxx.aws.com"    
    },
    {  
        "name":"SES_FROM_EMAIL",
        "value":"abc@gmail.com"  
    },
    {  
        "name":"SES_TO_EMAIL",
        "value":"123@gmail.com"  
    }
```

File 2:

```
   {
      "name": "SES_ENABLED",
      "value": "false"
    },

    {  
        "name":"SES_FROM_EMAIL",
        "value":"xyz@gmail.com"  
    },
    {  
        "name":"SES_ADDRESS",
        "value":"emails-xyzyzyz.aws.com"    
    }
```

In the above two files the name variable will be same but the values are different and the ordering is different and also there is an extra field in file 1

i.e

```
{
   "name": "SES_TO_EMAIL"
   "value": "123@gmail.com"
}
```

From file1 how can i compare file2  for common "name" variables present and also if any field is missing in file2 than file1, how can I get that.

**For example:**

After comparing file1 to file2 , I need to get output like `"name": "SES_TO_EMAIL"` is not present in file2.

Any solution will be very useful.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Use Regex to filter the text to your needs. https://regexone.com/

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802076/comparing-two-files-of-jsons-and-resulting-json-difference) out. This might help you.

Comment: one option is to create a hashset  of all name in file1 ,  Itterate file2 and check if present in hashset  if available remove from hashset(or do further processing )

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850289/comparing-two-json-files-shell-scripting

Comment: In Python3 I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27266178/6352008) answer as it works for nested dictionnaries as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each file contains a stream of objects, a simple [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) program as below would do the trick.

```
reduce inputs.name as $name ({}; .[input_filename] += [$name])
| (keys_unsorted | combinations(2)) as $pair
| (.[$pair[0]] - .[$pair[1]])[]
| "name: \(.) is not present in \($pair[1])"
```

Invocation:

```
jq -rnf prog.jq file1 file2 file3 ...
```

Comment: getting error,  Cannot index string with string "name"

Comment: @Bala that means your input samples do not truly represent your actual input. fix them and let me know

Comment: I am a bit confused oguz, Assuming my files are file1.json and file2.json. and file content inside is exactly as mentioned in question. can you edit your prog.jq file, please

Comment: @Bala JQ won't recognize that format. It should either be like `[{},{},{}]` (an array of objects), or `{}{}{}` (a stream of objects); `{},{},{}` is not a valid JSON value. I updated my answer to work with `{}{}{}` format.

Answer (score -1):

```py
def compare(files):
    # store all name into list of list
    names = [[prop['name'] for prop in file] for file in files]
    for i, name in enumerate(names):
        # create a temporary list
        temp_name = names.copy()
        # remove current name in list
        temp_name.pop(i)
        for n in name:
            for j, temp in enumerate(temp_name):
                if not (n in temp): # if name in not present in the other file, print it
                    print('name: {} is not present in file {}'.format(n, (j+1 if j < i else j + 2)))
```

this is my naive way, we need to store all the names in `list` and compare every name with that list. to use it simply

```py
import json
# open the first file
with open('file1.json', 'r') as file:
    file1 = json.load(file)
# open the second file
with open('file2.json', 'r') as file:
    file2 = json.load(file)
# then compare them
compare([file1, file2])
```

the output will be like this

```
name: SES_TO_EMAIL is not present in file 2
```